# Request for example tizen code, that scrolls a <div> with bezel

Tags: javascript, rotation, tizen

I'm looking for working web app in tizen, that can scroll a div with rotating bezel.

I'v already spent some hours trying to get it working... and I find myself reading the same links all over again for 3rd day :) :
https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/guides/web-application/user-interface/tizen-advanced-ui/applications-circular-ui/handling-rotary-events?langredirect=1#pagescroll

https://developer.tizen.org/ko/forums/web-application-development/scrolling-content-bezel?langswitch=ko

It does not work for me, although on another template app i was able to change some text, when bezel was rotated (my Gear S3). Scrolling the page is a bit different. It seems I have a problem with selecting correct DOM or event listener/ adding the scroller...

My example based on the links:

```js
window.onload = function () {
 
 var SCROLL_STEP = 50, /* Distance of moving scroll for each rotary event */
    page = document.getElementById('main'); /* Query with page ID */

page.addEventListener('popupshow', function popupOpenHandler(e) {
    var popup = e.target, /* Popup element */
        /* Element that has scroll */
        scroller = popup.querySelector('.ui-popup-wrapper'),

        /* Rotary event handler */
        rotaryEventHandler = function(e) {
            if (e.detail.direction === 'CW') {
                /* Right direction */
                scroller.scrollTop += SCROLL_STEP;
            } else if (e.detail.direction === 'CCW') {
                /* Left direction */
                scroller.scrollTop -= SCROLL_STEP;
            }
        };

    /* Register the rotary event */
    document.addEventListener('rotarydetent', rotaryEventHandler, false);

    /* Deregister the rotary event */
    popup.addEventListener('popuphide', function popupHideHandler() {
        popup.removeEventListener('popuphide', popupHideHandler, false);
        document.removeEventListener('rotarydetent', rotaryEventHandler, false);
    }, false);
}, false);

page.addEventListener('pagebeforeshow', function pageScrollHandler(e) {
    var page = e.target;
    elScroller = page.querySelector('.ui-scroller');

    /* Rotary event handler */
    rotaryEventHandler = function(e) {
        if (e.detail.direction === 'CW') {
            /* Right direction */
            elScroller.scrollTop += SCROLL_STEP;
        } else if (e.detail.direction === 'CCW') {
            /* Left direction */
            elScroller.scrollTop -= SCROLL_STEP;
        }
    };

    /* Register the rotary event */
    document.addEventListener('rotarydetent', rotaryEventHandler, false);

    /* Deregister the rotary event */
    page.addEventListener('pagebeforehide', function pageHideHandler() {
        page.removeEventListener('pagebeforehide', pageHideHandler, false);
        document.removeEventListener('rotarydetent', rotaryEventHandler, false);
    }, false);

}, false);
 
 
};
```

```css
* {
    font-family: Verdana, Lucida Sans, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0px auto;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
}

.contents {
 display: flex;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 height:320px;
}


.content_text {
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:5em;
 color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Tizen Wearable basic template generated by Samsung Wearable Web IDE"/>

    <title>Tizen Wearable Web IDE - Tizen Wearable - Tizen Wearable basic Application</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


<div class="ui-page ui-page-active" id="main">
   <header class="ui-header">
      <h2 class="ui-title">TAU Basic</h2>
   </header>
   <div class="ui-content">
      <a href="#popup" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>
      <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
   </div>
   <!--Popup-->
   <div id="popup" class="ui-popup">
      <div class="ui-popup-content">
        <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
  <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
  <p>Hello World!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-popup-footer ui-bottom-button">
         <a id="1btnPopup-cancel" href="#" class="ui-btn" data-rel="back">Check</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't work because you add event listener for "pagebeforeshow" too late.

Instead of this:

```
window.onload = function () {
 ...
};
```

try:

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
 ...
});
```

And move your `main.js` file above TAU library.

```
    <link href="tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="tau/wearable/theme/default/tau.circle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/style.circle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="tau/wearable/js/tau.js"></script>
</head>
```

I also encourage you to create a issue in our project on Github (https://github.com/Samsung/TAU) if you encounter any problems to improve.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Although I could not get it working this way...(perhaps there were another problems) I managed to find working solution, which is a bit different:

```js
(function() {
 
var page = document.getElementById('main');  // <div id="main" class="container">
 
document.getElementById('main').setAttribute('tizen-circular-scrollbar', '');

function rotaryDetentHandler (e) {
    var direction = e.detail.direction;

 if (direction === "CW") {
  page.scrollTop += 50;
 } 
 else if (direction === "CCW") {
  page.scrollTop -= 50;
 }

}
 
document.addEventListener('rotarydetent', rotaryDetentHandler); 




//add eventListener for tizenhwkey
document.addEventListener('tizenhwkey', function(e) {
    if (e.keyName === "back") {
        try {
            tizen.application.getCurrentApplication().exit();
        } catch (ignore) {
        }
    }
});


}());
```

```css
html,
body {
    width: 360px;
    height: 360px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

#news-view {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
     <meta name="description" content="Tizen Wearable basic template generated by Samsung Wearable Web IDE"/>
 
     <title>Tizen Wearable Web IDE - Tizen Wearable - Tizen Wearable basic Application</title>
 
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
     <script src="js/main.js"></script>
 </head>
 
 <body>
 
 
 
  <div id="main" class="container">

       
     <p>Hello World!</p>
   <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
   <p>Hello World!</p>
   <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
   <p>Hello World!</p>
   <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
   <p>Hello World!</p>
   <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
   <p>Hello World!</p>
   <p>Hello World!</p>
   <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
   <p>Hello World!</p>
   <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
   <p>Hello World!</p>
   <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
   <p>Hello World!</p>
   <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
   <p>Hello World!</p>
   <p>Hello World!</p>
   <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
   <p>Hello World!</p>
   <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
   <p>Hello World!</p>
   <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
   <p>Hello World!</p>
   <p>Hello World!!!!!</p>
   <p>Hello World!</p>        
              
  </div>
 
 
 
 
 </body>
 <script src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you used events "pagebeforeshow", "popup show", "popup hide". These events are specific for TAU framework and JQueryMobile so I thought that you use TAU in your app. That is probably why the solution did not work.

Your latest solution simply scrolls content in a web application without TAU library.